# Three20: Make a TTTableItem link to a TTViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, three20

I want my table items to show the disclosure arrow and link to another "details" screen.  Pretty standard.  Three20 is supposed to help with this.

In my TTListDataSource, I'm currently doing:

```
- (void)tableViewDidLoadModel:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    [super tableViewDidLoadModel:tableView];

    // Construct an object that is suitable for the table view system
    // from each domain object that we retrieve from the TTModel.
    for (Listing *result in [(id<SearchResultsModel>)self.model results]) {             
        NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"myapp://listing", result.theID];           
        TTTableSubtitleItem *item = [TTTableSubtitleItem itemWithText:result.title subtitle:result.desc imageURL:result.imageURL defaultImage:nil URL:url accessoryURL:nil];
        [self.items addObject: item];
    }
}
```

But I need to pass an object (not just a string) to the `TTViewController` when the [TTTableItem](http://github.com/facebook/three20/blob/master/src/Three20/TTTableItem.h) is clicked.  I know that you can pass an `NSDictionary` object to a 
[TTViewController](http://github.com/facebook/three20/blob/master/src/Three20/TTViewController.h) using: [TTNavigator](http://github.com/facebook/three20/blob/master/src/Three20/TTNavigator.h)'s `[[TTNavigator navigator] openURL: query: animated:]` method.

However, since I'm trying to open this URL from a `TTTableItem`, I don't know how to use openURL method with it where I can pass a query `NSDictionary` object, since all it takes as an `NSString` "URL" parameter.

I read the discussion [here](http://groups.google.com/group/three20/browse_thread/thread/1f70e6b36ce8999b) however I'd really, really like to avoid having to modify the original Three20 code.  If it can properly be extended, that would be fine.

**What's the simplest way I can make my table item's open up a `TTViewController` and pass an object (such as an `NSDictionary`)**?

Comment: I posted a similar question on the Three20 Google Group and will post here if a solution comes from there first.

Comment: How to do this on a TableItem?

I dont know how to call didSelectRowAtIndexPath in my DataSource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Google Group...
http://groups.google.com/group/three20/msg/5cdbbaf753dc52a1

Answer (score 3):

If you look at http://three20.info/core/navigation they show you how to do this without overriding the `didSelectObject` method.

In a nutshell, you can assign a URL to an object (via a category for NSObject) which is mapped to a URL for the controller that is hosting the table. The handler can then open another URL passing the appropriate objects in the query dictionary.